# Ubuntu 14.04 Update Failure

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am trying to use **sudo apt-get update** to update my Ubuntu but i have been getting this error code and i dont know how to proceed. 
I am a newbie with ubuntu.

Thanks.
Below is the error code it shows after trying to update

```
Fetched 32.9 MB in 2min 49s (195 kB/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```